# Need Help extracing a list from a string using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a little trouble extracting these two lists '['item1', 'item2', 'item3'] ['item4', 'item5']' here is an example of the code I have attempted

```
import re

pattern_matcher = re.compile(r"(\[,\]])")

alien_string = "Offering ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'] (4331)[6785]    Requesting ['item4', 'item5'] (6998)[6766]. {0.255457} (0 left in queue)..."

matches = pattern_matcher.fullmatch(alien_string)

print(matches)
```

The output I received was

```
Output: None
```

I would like to know how I can go about extracting these two lists from this long string specifically ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'] and ['item4', 'item5']

Comment: Your string doesn't contain `[,]]` which is the only thing your regex matches. Can you explain why you were hoping this would do anything useful?

Comment: Your pattern looks for a `[` immediately followed by a `,`, but that never occurs.

Comment: I was hoping that '''[,]]''' would match the style of a list and therefore just print them both. I have never tried pulling a list out of a string before, so this is new to me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What do you need help with exactly? This code has multiple different problems (wrong regex, wrong `re` function). It'd probably help more for you to do a regex tutorial and read the [docs for the `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Please read [ask]. You can [edit] if necessary.

Comment: FWIW, `[6785]` and `[6766]` are also valid Python lists. How do you want to avoid matching them?

Comment: This is where I'm clueless. I was hoping that [6785] and [6766] could be avoided by specifying that the list must not contain any integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\[[^\]]+?(?:, [^\]]+?)+\]")

alien_string = "Offering ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'] (4331)[6785]    Requesting ['item4', 'item5'] (6998)[6766]. {0.255457} (0 left in queue)..."

matches = re.findall(pattern, alien_string)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Result:

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
['item4', 'item5']
```

Explanation:

- `\[` matches the first bracket
- `[^\]]` matches anything that isnt a closed bracket
- `[^\]]*?` matches a variable number of non-bracket chars until the comma
- `(?:` starts a non-capturing group (used for `findall`)

The rest should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Great explanation I couldn't find any information in regards to this online. I will definitely use this example to enhance my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to split the line and match each part:

```
import re
alien_string = "Offering ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'] (4331)[6785]    Requesting ['item4', 'item5'] (6998)[6766]. {0.255457} (0 left in queue)..."
parts = alien_string.split('    ')
lists = [re.search(r'(\[(.*?)\])', part).group(0) for part in parts]
print(lists)
```

output

```
["['item1', 'item2', 'item3']", "['item4', 'item5']"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to look further into this example.